# Request focus to a view in and Activity's window's decorView

Tags: android, focus

I have added a LinearLayout in an Activity's window's decorview. Like this,

```
LinearLayout mylayout = ...;
((ViewGroup)MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(mylayout);
mylayout.bringToFront();
```

Well, everything works fine till now. But the problem is if I have a EditText in `mylayout`, then it can't get focus. Like, `clearFocus()` gives focus to a focusable view starting from top. I want that this happens for `mylayout`, and even if there are no focusables. I want the LinearLayout to hold the focus.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set focus to your EditText using requestFocus like this in your layout

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```